# Why do open-source projects avoid .msi? Is there a blocking reason?

Tags: cross-platform, windows-installer

I've noticed that cross-platform tools, and open-sourced projects tend to make or use installers that use NSIS, or bitrock, or other .exe based installers. And I'm not talking about wrapping an exe around an msi, these installers completely avoid touching the msi system.

Is there something particularly difficult about supporting msi? Or are just the popular free tools never bothered to support msi. It seems like WiX is for windows-only applications.

Comment: My motivation for this question is determining if it's worth fighting for using my old installation creation software for windows on these new cross-platform (oxs,linux,windows) projects I'm working on.

Comment: FWIW, assuming the projects are interesting and worthwhile, I'd be willing to donate some of my time creating MSI's using WiX for your projects.  Just email me.

Comment: There are plenty of exceptions out there (python for example distributes .msi files), but agreed it's less common.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess (based on 17 years of installation experience on the Windows Platform)

Windows Installer is a different beast.  It's declarative instead of imperative and has a fairly steep learning curve.  Most developers don't want to touch installers with a 10 foot pole.  With NSIS and others it at least "feels" like programming so the developers come away with it feeling it's a superior way to make installers.

But it's not...

You mention WiX is for Windows only. Well, yah, MSI is for Windows only.

Comment: I should have been more clear about that sentence. I meant you can only run WiX on Windows. AFAIK. So if a nightly build server is linux they couldn't use it.

Comment: It might be possible using mono and/or wine but it isn't designed for.  You could always scp/ssh your build over to a windows machine.  We do that at work all the time.

Comment: I guess the best I can offer my client is one installer system for windows and one for the rest. Doesn't really fit the bill.

Comment: And that provides a really bad experience on Windows. I see this all the time... a multiplatform company creates an installer for Windows that acts like it's Unix and it almost always ends poorly.  Here is an example: http://blog.iswix.com/2010/09/worst-installer-i-ever-seen.html

Comment: I'd be willing to discuss on the phone with you if you'd like to understand why MSI is important to your customer's customers even if your customer doesn't know it.